# I have this issue when I try to install nativescript on my mac. can anyone help me?

Tags: node.js, npm, nativescript

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: marked-terminal@3.1.1
npm WARN Found: marked@1.1.1
npm WARN node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/marked
npm WARN   marked@"1.1.1" from nativescript@8.1.4
npm WARN   node_modules/nativescript
npm WARN     nativescript@"*" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer marked@"^0.4.0 || ^0.5.0" from marked-terminal@3.1.1
npm WARN node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/marked-terminal
pm WARN   node_modules/nativescript
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: marked@0.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/marked
npm WARN   peer marked@"^0.4.0 || ^0.5.0" from marked-terminal@3.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/marked-terminal

changed 623 packages, and audited 624 packages in 2m

30 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

28 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 8 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I got this message when I install typescript. How do I solve this problem?